# Iterate through a 2d Array and listing all of the entries

Tags: javascript, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a function that iterates through a 2d Array, every Array has a song and an interpreter and the function is supposed to run a loop and list every song with it's interpreter. The problem is that it only lists the last song and interpreter, what am I missing so it lists all of them?:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="2d"> </ul>
```

**JS**

```
var twoDArray = [
  ["I did it my way", "Frank Sinatra"],
  ["Respect", "Areta Franklin"],
  ["Imagine", "John Lennon"]
];

function iterative( songs ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < songs.length; i += 1) {
    document.getElementById("2d").innerHTML =  "<li>" + songs[i][0] + " by " + songs[i][1] + "</li>";
 }
}

iterative(twoDArray);
```

Comment: `+=` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are setting the innerHtml every time you loop, so it will over-write itself every time except the last. You want to do this instead

```
  document.getElementById("2d").innerHTML +=  "<li>" + songs[i][0] + " by " + songs[i][1] + "</li>";
```

Comment: Of course...Thanks for pointing that out. Accepting when it allows me.

Comment: @sergi if this fixed your issue will you mark as your answer please

Comment: Sorry, looks like I forgot to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. Hope this helps.

```js
const twoDArray = [
  ["I did it my way", "Frank Sinatra"],
  ["Respect", "Areta Franklin"],
  ["Imagine", "John Lennon"]
];
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
twoDArray.forEach(pair => {
  const li = `<li>${pair[0]} by ${pair[1]}</li>`;
  ul.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', li);
})
```

```html
HTML:

<ul id="2d"> </ul>
```